# How to show a div after all inputs filled out

Tags: jquery

When a user fills out all fields, the div should show. How do I reference the three input options so the div will show only when all three have a value?

HTML:

```
Type here:<input type="text" id="gname">
Type here:<input type="text" id="gname2">
Select:<select id="gname3">
  <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>

<div id="number">
  Test 
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
$('#gname').bind('keyup change',function(){
    if(this.value.length > 0){
      $('#number').show();
}
else {
    $('#number').hide();
}
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
  #number { display: none; height: 100px; border: solid 1px #ddd; }
</style>
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track - just set three variables (I'd make them booleans) when your condition is met all three will be true. When that happens, show the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example

```
$('input[type="text"], select').bind('keyup change',function(){

    // get elements that are empty.
    var empty = $('input[type="text"], select').map(function(index, el) {
        return !$(el).val().length ? el : null;
    }).get();

    // could also be placed outside of the function
    var number = $('#number');

    // check if there are any empty elements, if there are none, show numbers, else hide number.
    !empty.length ? number.show() : number.hide();
});
```

This will loop over your elements (provided in example) and check if those elements have an empty value. it will then return an array of elements that are empty.

There then is a check if the array of elements is empty, show the number, else, hide the number.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x3yh/1/)

Comment: It works great in a normal page, but how to let it works inside bootstrap modal? '<div id="aggiungi" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="invio">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content"> '

Comment: I understand that the problem is the class="modal fade"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to validate if form is dirty with this :

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
    var hash = 0;
    if (this.length == 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        char = this.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash<<5) - hash) + char;
        hash = hash & hash;
    }
    return hash;
};

$(function() {
    var $form = $('form');
    $form.data('checksum', $form.serialize().hashCode())
    $form.submit(function() {
        var initialChecksum = $(this).data('checksum');
        var currentChecksum = $(this).serialize();
        var isDirty = initialChecksum != currentChecksum;
        $('#isDirty').val(isDirty);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you can't use forms validation or would like another (perhaps more easy-to-read) method, you can do the following...

**Note: I changed the script to detect if the selected option value has a zero length; if your default option is a blank value (and has a disabled attribute set to 'disabled') this will work. See my demo for the full example.

**Javascript**

```
$('#gname').bind('keyup change', function(){
    var show = true;
    // Check each child input for data.
    $(this).children('input').each(function(i){
        if($(this).val().length==0){
            show = false;
        };
    });

    // If no options are selected in the "Select" element, set [show] flag to false.
    if(($('#gname select :selected').length==0 || $('#gname select :selected').val().length==0)){
        show = false;
    };

    // Hide or show the necessary elements based on the [show] flag.
    if(show){
        $('#number').show();
    } else {
        $('#number').hide();
    }
});
```

**Edit:**
I fixed the JS fiddle to point to the updated link.

[JS Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NqXW6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
$('#gname').bind('keyup change', function(){
    var show = true;
    for(child in $(this).children){
        if(child.is(':empty')){
            show = false; //Could break here if you want. 
        } 
    }

    if(show){
        $('#number').show();
    } else {
        $('#number').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Does `.is(':empty')` work with select & option tags?

Comment: I suggest you to use something to check if form is dirty or pristine.

Comment: No luck on this johnsoe. As soon as one input gets data, the div shows. If possible, the div should only show when all three are filled out.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @docta_faustus See my answer below for a js fiddle demo of how you can make this work.

Comment: This works also in bootstrap with class="modal fade". The problem is that I have more than one input tag and the hidden DIV, show up as the first input tag is leaved