# How to show a div after specific inputs are filled out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working of this: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20055898/how-to-show-a-div-after-all-inputs-filled-out)
I was wondering how to change this around so that it could work with specific parts of a form, rather than all of it.

I have managed to get it working using ID's only, but not classes.

I have got this so far:

```
            $('.weeks').bind('keyup change',function(){
            // get elements that are empty.
            var empty = $('.weeks').map(function(index, el) {
                return !$(el).val().length ? el : null;
            }).get();

            // could also be placed outside of the function
            var tick = $('#tick3');
            var cross = $('#cross3');

            // check if there are any empty elements, if there are none, show numbers, else hide number.
            !empty.length ? tick.show() : tick.hide();
            !empty.length ? cross.hide() : cross.show();
        });
```

and this is the html:

```
<span class="checked tick" id="tick3"><img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/9/d/J/p/D/g/check-grey-md.png" width="38px" style="margin-top: -10px;" /></span>
                    <span class="checked" id="cross3"><img src="http://mypad.northampton.ac.uk/12402247/files/2014/02/red-wrong-cross-hi-23y1kex.png" width="38px" style="margin-top: -10px;" /></span>
<table>
                    <tr class="bottom">
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="allWeeks" class="weeks" name="all" onClick="allWeeks(this)"></input>
                            <label for="allWeeks">1-15</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="defWeeks" class="weeks" checked name="default" onClick="defaultWeeks(this)"></input>
                            <label for="defWeeks">1-12</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="oddWeeks" class="weeks" name="odd" onClick="oddWeeks(this)"></input>
                            <label for="oddWeeks">Odd</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="evenWeeks" class="weeks" name="even" onClick="evenWeeks(this)"></input>
                            <label for="evenWeeks">Even</label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <button id="clearWeeks">Clear</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bottom">
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="1" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks odd_weeks" checked name="1" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="1">1</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="2" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks even_weeks" checked name="2" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="2">2</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="3" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks odd_weeks" checked name="3" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="3">3</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="4" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks even_weeks" checked name="4" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="4">4</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="5" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks odd_weeks" checked name="5" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="5">5</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="6" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks even_weeks" checked name="6" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="6">6</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="bottom">
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="7" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks odd_weeks" checked name="7" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="7">7</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="8" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks even_weeks" checked name="8" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="8">8</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="9" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks odd_weeks" checked name="9" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="9">9</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="10" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks even_weeks" checked name="10" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="10">10</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="11" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks odd_weeks" checked name="11" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="11">11</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="12" class="weeks all_weeks default_weeks even_weeks" checked name="12" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="12">12</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="13" class="weeks all_weeks odd_weeks" name="13" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="13">13</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="14" class="weeks all_weeks even_weeks" name="14" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="14">14</label>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="15" class="weeks all_weeks odd_weeks" name="15" onClick="changed_check();"></input>
                            <label for="15">15</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

What I am hoping to do is to display a tick if at least one of the checkboxes with the class weeks is checked, and if none are then it displays a cross.

Code for checkboxes and clear button, so 1-12 checks 1-12, etc.:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#allWeeks").click(function () {
                $(".all_weeks").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
                $("#defWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#evenWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#oddWeeks").attr('checked', false);
            });

            $("#defWeeks").click(function () {
                $(".all_weeks").attr('checked', false);
                $(".default_weeks").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
                $("#allWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#evenWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#oddWeeks").attr('checked', false);
            });

            $("#oddWeeks").click(function () {
                $(".all_weeks").attr('checked', false);
                $(".odd_weeks").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
                $("#allWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#defWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#evenWeeks").attr('checked', false);
            });

            $("#evenWeeks").click(function () {
                $(".all_weeks").attr('checked', false);
                $(".even_weeks").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
                $("#allWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#defWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#oddWeeks").attr('checked', false);
            });

            $("#clearWeeks").click(function () {
                $(".all_weeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#allWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#defWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#oddWeeks").attr('checked', false);
                $("#evenWeeks").attr('checked', false);
            });
        });
```

Any help is appreciated

[UPDATED Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/6SPfT/1/)

Comment: You can refer to the target object that triggered the event using `$(this)`.

Comment: @Alon, How would I implement that, as I need it to replace the cross with a tick if at least one of the checkboxes are checked, and then again replace the tick with a cross if none of them are checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say that it is obvious what you are trying to do, but it is certain that calling .val() on a checkbox element is not going to get you the result you want. Here is a nice way of getting the array of empty (as in unchecked) elements that should work:

```
var empty = $('.weeks').filter(':not(:checked)');
```

You've subsequently made it clear that you want to know if any box is checked and, if so, to show the checkmark; otherwise show the 'X'. You should therefore get an array of checked elements, not empty ones:

```
var checked = $('.weeks').filter(':checked');
```

And then show/hide the images accordingly:

```
checked.length ? tick.show() : tick.hide();
checked.length ? cross.hide() : cross.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but only when I remove another piece of code which I have added above. If I leave my previous code, which I need, it doesn't work.

Comment: OK. Add this at the end of each of your click handler functions: $('.weeks:first').trigger('change');